# ONLY one client receive message in multiple client's server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, client

My target is print the message from function `result` on the client's screen. But only ONE client can received the message...

---

The part of client.py is here

```
def PlayGame(clientSocket, msg):
invalid = "NO!"
if ("/guess " in msg):
    msg1 = msg.split(" ")[1]
    print("Hi1\n")
    if msg1 == "true" or msg1 == "false":
        print("Hi11")
        clientSocket.send(msg1.encode())
        print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode())
        print("!")
        return '1'

    else:
        clientSocket.send(invalid.encode())
        print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode())
        print("2")
        return '2'
elif msg == "":
    return '2'
else:
    clientSocket.send(invalid.encode())
    print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode())
    print("3")
    return '2'

def main(argv):
            msg=""
            while (PlayGame(clientSocket, msg)!=1):
                msg = input()
```

---

Any part of the server.py

```
guess_box = []
guess = bool(random.randint(0, 1))
    def result(connectionSocket, guess_box,  addr, addr_l):
        a = 0
        if(guess_box[0] == guess_box[1]):
            msg = "Tie!!"
            connectionSocket.send(msg.encode())
            return '2'
        elif(guess_box[0] == guess):
            msg = "Player 1 Wins!"
            a+=1
            connectionSocket.send(msg.encode())
            return '2'
        elif(guess_box[1] == guess):
            msg = "Player 2 Wins!"
            a+=1
            connectionSocket.send(msg.encode())
            return '2'
    
    def TF(connectionSocket, var, guess_box, addr, addr_l):
        msg = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("recv:",msg)
        if(msg == 'true'):
            msg = 'True'
            var = str(var)
            msg = bool(msg == var)
            guess_box.append(msg)
            return 'ok'
        elif(msg == 'false'):
            msg = 'False'
            var = str(var)
            msg = bool(msg == var)
            guess_box.append(msg)
            return 'ok'
        else:
            print(msg)
            statement = "4002 Unrecognized message!!"
            connectionSocket.send(statement.encode())
            return 'again'
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client

    def run(self):
    ...
    print("guess is:", guess)
    
                    while (len(guess_box) != 2):
                        TF(connectionSocket, guess, guess_box, addr, addr_l)
    
                    print("start")
                    result(connectionSocket, guess_box, addr, addr_l)
    ...
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Some of the issues: `GameHallMsg` does `return 1` for `'list'` and invalid `'enter'` messages while it should rather `return 'wait'`. The `while(1): #waiting the other player` is an end- and pointless loop.

Comment: @Armali I have updated the code and write the expected output. Thanks for the advises again!

Comment: I think the problem is: the second client that input the command /guess, cannot receive the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding only the one problem you address:

> print the message from function result on the client's screen. But only ONE client can received the message

The problem comes from the use of a different thread for each client. The thread which receives a guess as first stays in its

```
                        while (len(guess_box) != 2):
                            print(guess_box)
                            TF(connectionSocket, guess, guess_box)
```

loop and waits for another message, which doesn't come. The thread which receives a guess as second sends the result to its own client only.

I don't think there's a sensible way to fix this while keeping this <strike>d</strike>threaded approach.

> Can I change the structure of my code by using those functions I implemented?

Here's a substitute for the `while True` loop in `server_run` that doesn't require changes in *those functions* other than `server_run`.

```
        from select import select
        connections = []
        room_connection = {}
        for reads in iter(lambda: select([serverSocket]+connections, [], [])[0], []):
            for ready in reads: # for each socket which select reports is readable
                if ready == serverSocket:   # it's the server socket, accept new client
                    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
                    connections.append(connectionSocket)# store the connection socket
                    while RecvFromClient(connectionSocket) == "NO": pass
                else:           # message (or disconnect) from a client
                    try: var = GameHallMsg(ready, ready, connections)
                    except socket.error: var = 'bye'
                    if var == 'bye':    # client finished, remove from list
                        connections.remove(ready)
                        ready.close()
                    elif var == 'wait': # store first player's connection
                        room_connection[current_rm_num.pop()] = ready
                    elif var == 'NO':
                        rtn_msg_4 = "4002 Unrecognized message"
                        ready.send(rtn_msg_4.encode())
                    elif var == 'jump':
                        readyroom = current_rm_num.pop()
                        # find and notify other player in the room
                        other = room_connection.pop(readyroom)
                        rtn_msg_2 = "3012 Game started. Please guess true or false"
                        other.send(rtn_msg_2.encode())
                        print("guess is:", guess)
                        # query and inform both players
                        guess_box = []
                        while TF(ready, True, guess_box) != 'ok': pass
                        while TF(other, True, guess_box) != 'ok': pass
                        result(ready, guess_box, ('', 0), [0])
                        result(other, guess_box, ('', 1), [0, 1])
                        room[readyroom] = 0
```

Comment: Can I change the structure of my code by using those functions I implemented? I am so sorry that I am not familiar with threading

Comment: This can be possible if errors in _those functions_ are corrected, namely the indexing of `state`, which in `RecvFromClient` is by `username.index`, but in `GameHallMsg` is by `addr_l.index`.

Comment: (And at one place `state` is set to the room number, while otherwise it's used as a counter.)

Comment: thanks for answering my doubts!
Acutally I've found a "solution" for my problem on github:https://github.com/yeeaayee/Computer_Network_Coursework/blob/master/Assignment%201/GameClient.py

But can I use my existing code to do the samething with the code above by just correcting the problems you rise? Thank you again!!!

Comment: I could suggest a changed `server_run` if the issue with `state` were corrected, but you'd have to do this in `RecvFromClient` or `GameHallMsg`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!! That means I do not need to pick up class & object at this moments .. haha

Comment: I added a suggestion changing `server_run` and using unmodified other functions.

Comment: Really thanks for your help!! But why is the change in server_run but not in the run in ServerThread? Isn't the run in ServerThread control the whole thread? I am so sorry that I am just learning multithread in other course recently..

Comment: The whole _ServerThread_ is inapplicable with this change, since there are no more threads. You'll note that the code from _ServerThread_ is essentially moved to `server_run`.